# How can I format a specific cell using the Ruby Spreadsheet library?

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet

Formatting a column or row seems to be no problem.  I've poked around the documentation a bunch, did some searches, and looked through the "methods" result on some spreadsheet objects and I can't figure out how to format a specific cell.  Has anyone done this?

The Spreadsheet library is here:
http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/
http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [set_format](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/Spreadsheet/Row.html#set_format-instance_method) method:

```
require 'spreadsheet'
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet

format = Spreadsheet::Format.new :color => :blue,
                                 :weight => :bold,
                                 :size => 18
row = sheet1.row(0)
row[0] = 'test0'
row[1] = 'test1'
row.set_format(0, format) # set format for the first cell

book.write 'C:\\test.xls'
```